# How to convert a CMSampleBuffer to a raw frame (say UYVY)?

Tags: swift, video-streaming, foundation

So I'm receiving a stream of video CMSampleBuffer-s and I want to push them through NDI (network device interface), so I need to convert then into some common format. (such as UYVY)

```
class SampleHandler: RPBroadcastSampleHandler {
    override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
        switch sampleBufferType {
        case RPSampleBufferType.video:
          var imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
          // now I need to get a reference to a framebuffer (of type uint8_t*) in UYVY format
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by that: _stream of video CMSampleBuffer-s_? Can you please share example of your stream?

Comment: @vpoltave I'm hoping I did answer your question. I'm quite new to all this.